# How to add simple text in a log file

Tags: python-3.x, logging, formatting

I am using the Python `logging' module to log specific occurrences during processing.

```
 import logging
 from logging import config

 #Start Log
 enable_logging(log_folder, log_file)
 fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(log_file))
 rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
 rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
 rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

 rootLogger.info("***Begin Comparison of National Summaries***")
```

It basically prints out messages like this in the log:

`Wed, 26 Feb 2020 16:08:40 INFO     ***Begin Comparison of National Summaries*** 
 Wed, 26 Feb 2020 16:08:42 INFO     Population Passed 
 Wed, 26 Feb 2020 16:08:42 INFO     Housing Units Passed 
 Wed, 26 Feb 2020 16:08:42 INFO     Area Passed 
 Wed, 26 Feb 2020 16:10:04 WARNING  SFHA Pop for CO_FIP: 1003 differ by 18413.0 people`

At the end of this log, I want to add some summarization messages, but I don't want to include the date and log level, etc... Basically, something that will look like this:

```
 Geography summaries 

 Changes since last update

               Matched    not Matched
 Counties        x (%)        y(%)
 Communiites     90%          10%
 CD              92%          8%
 HUC8            90%          10%
 Zip Codes       89%          11%
```

How could I format the logger to just write simple text like the above?